# Create a method that can initialize a new object from another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

What is the correct structure to be able to call a class from another class?

I can call `MyObject.new` by using `MyModule::MyClass::MyObject.new()`
However, I would prefer to call it using:

`MyModule::MyClass.myobject.new()`

How do I structure my code to by able to do this?

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
     class MyObject
        def initialize(value)
          @value = value
        end

        def method1
          "This is a #{value}"
        end
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would you do this? `MyModule::MyClass::MyObject.new()` is the right way to create a new instance of `MyObject`, not `MyModule::MyClass.myobject.new()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a method `myobject` on `MyClass` which returns `MyObject`...

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
     class MyObject
     end

     def self.myobject; return MyObject; end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a variable of some class and want to create a new object of the same class. Assuming that your classes all have an empty constructor, you could do a

```
myobject.class.new()
```

If you want to also have the new object the same internal state as the other one, write a method

```
 class MyMethod
     def clone
       ...
     end
 end
```

which performs this task.

Answer (score 0):

The Answers here are right, but don't do this it's not standard and will be confusing for anyone who reads your code.

```
MyModule::MyClass.my_object_instance
class MyClass
  def self.my_object_instance
    MyObject.new 
  end
end
```

this could be better to create a factory method that returns a new instance of the class if want a shorter way to create an instance of the class.

Comment: Rails does this all the time, what do you think active record does?

Comment: could you give a code example from rails to what do you mean?

Comment: Any belongs to or has many relationship does this, in a similar way.

Comment: you can check the source code of belongs_to  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fb3ecbf130e141688782bafb7da979bf0ecedf1a/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1657 
simply you can think about it as a class method in ActiveRecord::Base  and because of inheritance, you can use the method inside the class body to define an association